# Should I create a flash file for each screen size?

Tags: flash, resolution, aspect-ratio

I created a swf file for one my clients using a screen size of 1024px x 768px (4:3 ratio), now my client wants to re-use the video in a bigger screen (TV) that still uses a 4:3 ratio but the screen size is considerably bigger (I do not have the exact size yet).
Do I need to recreate the flash file using images that fit the new screen size, or the fact that they both use a 4:3 aspect ratio means that the image quality will not suffer?

Comment: Stretching the images will have quality issues, but stretching from 1024x768 to (say) 1280x1024 won't be particularly noticeable - a little fuzzy maybe. Stretching from 640x480 to 1600x1200 would probably look horrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what your SWF contains. If it's a video, then it makes sense to have different sizes (such as HD vs SD). However, if it's an application or timeline animation, you can look at setting [Stage scale mode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#scaleMode).

Usually when you create apps you would make them fluid so that they can resize depending on where they are, either full screen or within a set width and height.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can create SWF file for all screens, or only background, and just centerlize your main content, it's frequently decision, here some example how to do it:

**First of all, let's add listener for resize event**

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeListener);
```

**In addition, function which will resize your content (or BG).**

```
function resizeListener (e:Event):void {
     mc.x = 0; 
     mc.y = 0;
     mc.width = stage.stageWidth; 
     mc.height = stage.stageHeight;
}
```

Also, don't forget to create MC with **Top Left** register point. And add this align commands for your SWF file in your code:

```
 stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
 stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

Hope this help you.