# Optimising for all Screen Sizes - Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm making a game that goes into fullscreen mode when started up. I want to be able to optimise my game assets for all user's screen sizes. I have some code that traces the sizes of the user's screen size, but I'm not sure how I'd use this to optimise the game assets to fit the user's screen size.

Does anybody know how I could do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "optimizing for all user's screen sizes"?

Comment: Add event listener for Event.RESIZE to the stage and then handle everything in the callback. I can not expand on this unless you told me what are those assets you are talking about. Bitmaps? Vectors?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on many factors in your game, but if you just want to know how to create resize method in your game, check out this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681344/2009788